# How can I use setInterval to move an object with bouncing effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there this is my firts question, I'm just learning...

I want to have an object called ball bouncing from left 0 to left 300 and backwards. I have the following code so far, but I can't get the ball to come back properly. I shouldn't use any other functions than the ones that are already in the following code:

```js
var velocity = 20;
var position = 0;
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');

function start (){ 
  let arranca = setInterval(function(){
    if (position == 300) {
        if (position !== 0) {
          moverd();
        }else{
          movera();
        }
    }else{
      movera();
    }
  },200);
}
function movera(){
  let edge2 = 300;
  if(position != edge2){
    position = position + velocity; 
    ball.style.left = position + 'px';
    console.log('adelante: '+position);
  }  
}

function moverd(){
  let edge1 = 0;
  if (position != edge1){
        position = position - velocity;
        ball.style.left = position + 'px';
        console.log('atras: '+position);
  } 
}

start();
```

```html
<div id="ball" style="
  z-index:5;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:green"></div>
```

Comment: Besides the velocity you also need to keep a variable for the current direction; alter this direction when the ball hits a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var velocity = 20;
var position = 0, forward = false;
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');

function start (){ 
  let arranca = setInterval(function(){
    if (position == 300 || position == 0) {
        forward = !forward;
    }
    if(forward){
        movera();
    }
    else{
        moverd();
    }
  },200);
}
function movera(){
    position = position + velocity; 
    ball.style.left = position + 'px';
    console.log('adelante: '+position); 
}

function moverd(){
    position = position - velocity;
    ball.style.left = position + 'px';
    console.log('atras: '+position);
}

start();
```

```html
<div id="ball" style="
  z-index:5;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:green"></div>
```